# How to record and create a JMX for an application only compatible in Microsoft Edge(Compatible mode IE5)

Tags: jmeter, scripting, performance-testing, microsoft-edge

I have to do performance testing of an application only compatible in Microsoft Edge(Compatible mode IE5).Need to record the application and test in Jmeter.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the web application the main source for determining the client browser from its end is looking at [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header.

So if you **really** need to mimic the 23-years-old-browser it's sufficient to send the relevant User-Agent using JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)

[image]

Also you might be interested about the next funny fact: [according to JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

the same applicable to technologies like [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) or [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macromedia_Flash) or whatever else - you won't be simulate it in JMeter with 100% accuracy. The network footprint if any - yes, but no client-side impact.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from Dmitri is valid.
You can set User-agent value to something relevant for the browser you want to simulate/fake.

```
Name = User-Agent
Value = Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
```

In JMeter this is available in HTTP Header Manager. This component controls the headers for all of the requests you send.

Regarding the recording, I think it is better to use HTTP request samplers to simulate all the requests you want.